# Як сказати 'Поздравляю с приобретением?'

Tags: переклад

Добридень! Виникли труднощі з перекладом конструкції "Поздравляю с приобретением". Інтернет-ресурси надають лиш окремий переклад слова, як-от: набуток, надбання тощо, та на мій погляд не звучить. Цілої шуканої фрази я не стрічала. Як правильно? Охоче послухаю ваші думки.

P.S. (перенесено з коментарів): В моєму випадку — придбання знайомими нової автівки.

Comment: Якщо хочете зробити приємне клієнту, то скажіть "Дякую за покупку!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можна побачити що на сайті російсько-українських словників [r2u.org.ua "приобретение"](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) перекладається як:

> Надба́ння, придба́ння, набу́ток. *Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)*

Тобто якщо перекладати дослівно то буде щось на кшталт *"вітаю з придба́нням"*, або *"вітаю з набутком"*.

Але хотілося б зауважити, що вживання абстрактних іменників (а також заміна дієслів іменниками), за якими може ховатися будь-яка конкретика - типове для бюрократичної, канцелярської мови. Так, наприклад, цей "набуток" може бути штопором, а може бути маєтком на Мальдівах. Також таке абстрагування зручне для виробників вітальних листівок або шаблонів в мессенджерах, бо максимально охоплює потенційних покупців або користувачів які зроблять перепост.

Прикладом типового канцелярського слова є слово "захід". Коли пишуть "проведено захід" - це може бути як концерт, так і роботи по благоустрою (не "прибирали територію", а "відбувся захід з благоустрою"). А коли "вжито заходів" - то може бути що насправді відкрито кримінальне провадження.

У випадку вітання знайомих краще конкретизувати із чим саме ви вітаєте, наприклад **"Вітаю з новою автівкою"**. Це буде відчуватись саме як ваше персональне вітання, а не використання шаблона (хіба що ви використовуєте типовий шаблон з іронією).

Comment: Ґречно дякую! Надалі знатиму.